# How to animate a popover on iPhone, iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller, popover

I've got a popover showing up on button click, but it does not animate. I want it to start out at a zero size and grow to be the correct size similar to facebooks carrot action on a post. Any help is very appreciated. Code below:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    let popover = PopoverController()
    popover.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    popover.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 100)

    let popoverPresentationController = popover.popoverPresentationController
    popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up
    popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as UIView
    popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds

    self.presentViewController(popover, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController!) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```swift
popoverPresentationController?.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
```

just before presenting.

Comment: This doesn't work